# Using a boolean to determine whether a certain UltraGrid column is the active column

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to call a subroutine only when a certain `UltraGridColumn` is active. 
In the `CellListSelect`method, I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
If UltraGrid.Rows(0).IsActiveColumn("my_Column") = True Then
   subroutine(parameters)
  Else
End If
```

But I've been unable to work out the correct way of doing this. Does it require a separate subroutine? Or can it be done in the format described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that your code is in the CellListSelect event handler, so you can write

```
if e.Cell.Column.Key = "my_Column") Then
    MessageBox.Show("my_Column")

    ....

End If
```

Being `e` the name of the instance of then `CellEventArgs` parameter passed to CellListSelect